# laravel session missing after refresh url take with get parameter

Tags: laravel, session, refresh

This is my parameters
 
`?query%5Bdevice_id%5D=&query%5Boperator_id%5D=&query%5Bcreated_at%5D=2017-11-15+00%3A00%3A00`
after web load finish.refresh this web,I found this connection will get a new session, I can not get data which in the last session .
So ,should I change my url or need change configure ?

Comment: What L version?

Comment: @Boris laravel 5.5